# anchor links in site map with sections

Tags: anchor, sitemap, sections

I use a lot of anchor links in my webpage because its only one page that scrolls down by clicking the menu.
Also I made al my pages in sections.

Now I'm busy with making my sitemap.xml for google but i'm not sure if i need to put in all the sections/anchor-links.

my menu is like:

```
<nav id="nav" role="navigation">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li>
                    <a class="selected firstnav" href="#home" tabindex="-1">
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#watdoenwij" tabindex="-1">
                        Wat doen wij
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#portfolio" tabindex="-1">
                        Portfolio
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#werkwijze" tabindex="-1">
                        Werkwijze
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#uwwebsite" tabindex="-1">
                        De Website
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="lastnav" href="#contact" tabindex="-1">
                        Offerte & Contact
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

as you can see I only use links to #contact/#portfolio etc etc.
Do i have to put all the links in my sitemap?

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php#contact
http://www.domain.com/index.php#uwwebsite
http://www.domain.com/index.php#portfolio
```

Doesn't seem right to me?
Maybe google is seeing it as double content...

And if I have to add it to my sitemap what link do i have to use?

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php#contact 
http://www.domain.com/#contact
```

Comment: This has already been answered [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22411/sitemap-to-display-hash-tag-links-or-not)

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn't include anchor links. They refer to the same page and the sitemap specifies how often that content changes, but it's all one page.